# Is there a shorthand syntax for list that allows symbols in Chicken Scheme?

Tags: chicken-scheme

When I write:

```
'(1 2 3)
```

I get a list:

```
(1 2 3)
```

When I write:

```
'some-symbol
```

I get:

```
some-symbol
```

When I write:

```
'('some-symbol)
```

I get:

```
((quote some-symbol))
```

I can of course write:

```
(list 'some-symbol)
```

and I get:

```
(some-symbol)
```

which is the desired output. Is it correct that I cannot quote a symbol in a list like:

```
'(some-symbol)
```

Is there some other shorthand for the list operator that I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote will quote the entire s-expression that follows. So, in that sense,

```
'(some-symbol)
```

will actually be a quoted list containing the symbol you're looking for.

The quote sign is a shorthand for `(quote ...)`, so

```
'(some-symbol)
```

is equivalent to

```
(quote (some-symbol))
```

Comment: So 'some-symbol on its own is a symbol, '(some-symbol) is a symbol inside a quoted list, but some-symbol on its own is an unbound variable (I haven't and don't wish to define it to anything). I'm trying to use these like Clojure's keyword (e.g. :some-symbol) which evaluate to themselves. I figure I can do this with Chicken scheme using symbols, but it will be tricky to write using that shorthand bc I will need to be careful about my quoting of symbols inside that shorthand.

Comment: CHICKEN also has [support for keywords](http://wiki.call-cc.org/man/4/Non-standard%20read%20syntax#keyword) :)  See also the [extended DSSSL lambda lists](http://wiki.call-cc.org/man/4/Extensions%20to%20the%20standard#extended-dsssl-style-lambda-lists) for info on how to use them.

Comment: Neat! Is there a unique value for these that is available in C? When I grab the C_word using C_symbol_value it appears to give me the symbol back. I'd like to be able to leverage these values meaningfully on the C side, but I'm concerned that the C_word ptr will be potentially different after GC. Thoughts?

Comment: Wow, that's pretty low-level stuff you're asking for ;) You are correct in that the C_word pointer will be moved around by the GC. You can use a [GC root](http://wiki.call-cc.org/man/4/Embedding#chicken_new_gc_root) to hold the object. Whenever you need it in C, re-fetch it from the root, which will contain its current location. You may also be able to get the symbol using `C_h_intern` or one of the related undocumented functions, but I'd consider that a bit more of a hassle. Note that you do not need to use `C_symbol_value` as keywords tend to have themselves as value.